# group By in sql not assigning the value

Tags: sql-server

i am having the value in column Description , 'TRANSPORT' , in that particular table the same value has two times, i need to make it as a single value , in that i am using group by . but its not assigning.

my query

```
 SELECT CONVERT(date, UC.USGDATE) as USGDATE, SG.DESCRIPTION, SG.SERVICEGRP
 FROM APP_SYUTILITYCHARGES UC LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_MYSERVICEITEM SI
      ON SI.SERVICEITEMID = UC.SERVICEITEMID LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_MYSERVICE MS
      ON MS.SERVICEID = SI.SERVICEID LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_SERVICEGROUP SG
      ON SG.SERVICEGRP = MS.SERVICEGRP
 WHERE UC.STAYID = @STAYID
 GROUP BY SG.SERVICEGRP, UC.USGDATE, SG.DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Please also provide input data and desired output data.

Comment: Have you tried using the `DISTINCT` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `group by` clause.  If you want to get one value per date, then you need the `CONVERT()` in the `GROUP BY` as well as the `SELECT`:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(date, UC.USGDATE) as USGDATE, SG.DESCRIPTION, SG.SERVICEGRP
 FROM APP_SYUTILITYCHARGES UC LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_MYSERVICEITEM SI
      ON SI.SERVICEITEMID = UC.SERVICEITEMID LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_MYSERVICE MS
      ON MS.SERVICEID = SI.SERVICEID LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TX_SERVICEGROUP SG
      ON SG.SERVICEGRP = MS.SERVICEGRP
 WHERE UC.STAYID = @STAYID
 GROUP BY SG.SERVICEGRP, CONVERT(date, UC.USGDATE), SG.DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this type of grouping `GROUP BY SG.SERVICEGRP,UC.USGDATE,SG.DESCRIPTION` , the combination may be unique so you will be get description two times.